# str_pad(mt_rand(1,999999),06,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT Generating similar numbers

Tags: random, numbers, generator

```
 str_pad(mt_rand(1,999999),06,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT
```

I have had this code snippet on my WordPress site since 8 months ago. The purpose was to assign each user that fills the form (WPForm) a unique user ID. It has always worked well until today when I noticed that four entries have the same ID (One yesterday and Three today). I am running Astra Theme. Does anyone know what the course could be?

Comment: How many users do you have?  You're limited to ~1M numbers but you're doing nothing to prevent collisions.  By definition `mt_rand()` can return duplicates.

Comment: the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) says that you'll have a ~50% chance of seeing duplicates when you have 1000 users (i.e `sqrt(n)`).  you need a surprisingly large space to have a reasonable chance of keeping things unique

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. There was no check to ensure that the column take unique values. Also, the duplication occurred when a user had to assist others fill the form. All the duplicates were from his end.